# Why is this crontab not working?

Tags: linux, crontab

I'm a crontab beginner. Why does this crontab do nothing? I would like it to run the script every minute.

```
1 * * * * /home/android/test.sh
```

If I just type /home/android/test.sh in the shell it works so the script itself works.

Someone suggested this is a dupe, but I don't think it is. As far as I can tell, this crontab should work, but it doesn't. 1 means once a minute as far as I am aware, correct me if I'm wrong.

This is what the test.sh script does, simply:

date >> /home/android/date.txt

It works when I run it on its own but is not run automatically by the crontab.

Comment: I'm sure it does work. Did you wait until 1 minute past the hour?

Comment: Yes, I tested it several times. If I just type /home/android/test.sh in the shell it works so the script itself works. Should the output show up directly in the terminal or elsewhere?

Comment: You waited several hours until 1 minute past the hour...? (Hint.)

Comment: Yes. In the script itself, I request date >> date.txt. So, appending the date to the date.txt file. This works when I run the script manually, but no matter how many hours I wait, crontab won't run the script, seemingly.

Comment: Okay, to be very clear: you know this crontab is set to only run at 1 minute past the hour? Please use "edit" to make that clear in your question.

Comment: Sorry Arjan, I'm a beginner and it's late. I would actually like this script to run every minute.

Comment: But it didn't work *"no matter how many hours I wait"* ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different time specification formats with crontab](http://superuser.com/questions/212501/different-time-specification-formats-with-crontab)

Comment: I tried to follow several of those specifications already before I posted here.

Comment: *That* you also did not add to your question. Good luck.

Comment: Ohoy Arjan, stop spamming please.

Comment: @poko does your script have `#!/bin/bash` at the top?

Comment: @zalmy Yes and I know the script is working because it works when I run it manually.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know what your script does, it might be that it works, but you just do not see its output. To actually see something, you might redirect its output to a file:

> `* * * * * (/home/android/test.sh > /tmp/cron-out.txt)`

Then you could check whether the output is what you intend to have.

Additionally you could look in your system log (some systems have a dedicated log in `/var/log/cron`).

If that does not help either, you could check whether the user you execute the command with has all permissions it needs to execute the script, read input and write the output.

To execute the script every minute you have to replace `1 * * * *` with `* * * * *`, `0-59 * * * *` or `*/1 * * * *`. The setting you provided would only execute every hour at minute 1 (e.g. 9:01, 10:01, ...).

Make sure that all permissions are in place:

1. The user that should execute the script should be either be the owner (u), in the group (g) of the file or the permissions for "others" (o) should be set accordingly. To set the user android as the owner of the file `sudo chown android /home/android/test.sh`. To change the files group to `yourgroup`, you can use `chgrp yourgroup /home/android/test.sh` (under the assumption that your android user is in the group `yourgroup`).
2. Depending on the way you want to grant the user the permissions, you should `sudo chmod u+rx /home/android/test.sh` (Example for the executing user to be the owner - for the other cases replace the `u` with `g` or `o`).
3. Create a crontab for the user `android`. Either as the `android` user itself execute `crontab -e` or with any other administrative user `sudo crontab -u android -e`.

Comment: I specified above the content of the test.sh script just now.

Comment: The problem is, test.sh works when I run it manually but is not run by cron.

Comment: Ok, does the user you set the crontab up for have the rights to read and execute the script and to write to the designated file?

Comment: @duelle, the crontab is run every hour (one minute after the hour), not every minute as the question asker wants. See the duplicate.

Comment: @Arjan: you're right. @poko: To execute your script every minute, your crontab entry should look like this: `* * * * * /home/android/test.sh`

Comment: Hi there, I have tested using * * * * * as well, no result. How do I check if the user has sufficient privileges?

Comment: I have tried using the same line in a crontab as sudoer as well, no results. I also tried adding my user id to crontab at etc/groups. No results.

Comment: Under the assumption that you want to execute the script as the user `android`, you can do the following to make sure you can execute it: 1. `sudo chown android /home/android/test.sh` This makes sure the user is the file owner. 2. `sudo chmod u+rx /home/android/test.sh` This gives the owner of the file the permission to read and execute the file (if that isn't the case already). 3. `sudo crontab -u android -e` lets you edit the crontab for your android user. Here you can add the `* * * * * /home/android/test.sh` if it isn't in the crontab of this user already.